# R Binance API HMAC SHA256 signed message

Tags: r, api, post, sha256, hmac

Im trying to send over signed api messages using the binance APIs I keep failing with a 404 error. can someone help me out with the below code please?

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(digest)


timestamp <- 1516941586 #as.numeric(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()))

post_message <- paste0(timestamp, 'public.api' ) # data_client.id = client 
id # data_key = key

sha.message <- toupper(digest::hmac('private.api', object = post_message, 
algo = 'sha256', serialize = F))

url <- 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account'

body = list('timestamp' = timestamp, 'signature' = sha.message)
body2 <- paste("?timestamp=",timestamp,"&signature=",sha.message, sep = "")


httr::POST(url, body2 = body, verbose())
```

here is the documentation https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on example under section "SIGNED Endpoint Examples for POST /api/v1/order" in the website, you can follow something similar. You will need to replace with your own apiKey and secretKey.

```
library(httr)
library(openssl)

url <- 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account'
apiKey <- "vmPUZE6mv9SD5VNHk4HlWFsOr6aKE2zvsw0MuIgwCIPy6utIco14y7Ju91duEh8A"
secretKey <- "NhqPtmdSJYdKjVHjA7PZj4Mge3R5YNiP1e3UZjInClVN65XAbvqqM6A7H5fATj0j"

timestamp <- 1516941586
recvWindow <- 1e20
postmsg <- paste0("timestamp=", timestamp, "&recvWindow=", recvWindow)
signature <- openssl::sha256(postmsg, key=secretKey)

GET(url, 
    add_headers("X-MBX-APIKEY"=apiKey),
    query=list(timestamp=timestamp, recvWindow=recvWindow, signature=signature), 
    verbose())
```

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction! But i receive this error: Timestamp for this request is outside of the recvWindow.... So i added query=list(recvWindow = '100000000000000000', timestamp=timestamp, signature=signature) and then i get this error: Signature for this request is not valid.

Comment: oh are the apiKey and secretKey correct? you will need to add recvWindow to the postmsg

Comment: they are correct. so like this for postmsg ? postmsg <- paste0("recvWindow=",'100000000000000000', "timestamp=", timestamp)

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work! I just had to write another get for the server time. thanks a lot !

Comment: i get 401 Unauthorized when i run the code. i presume that the apiKey and secretKey are not live keys

Comment: that may be useful in the future as well if i have latency issues. thanks!

Comment: @FedericoMarchese I can't seem to figure out the solution from your comments. Could you please post your code?